# Unable to read cookies with brackets in name (Java EE 8/Tomcat 8)

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies

I am attempting to both set and get a cookie that has brackets in the name. I am able to do this in PHP, but reading back the cookie in Java isn't working for me. Here is the code to set the cookies in my JSP:

```
Cookie testCookie = new Cookie("test[cuid]", "test1");
Cookie testCookie2 = new Cookie("test", "test2");

testCookie.setMaxAge(60);
testCookie2.setMaxAge(60);

response.addCookie(testCookie);
response.addCookie(testCookie2);
```

Here is the code to read the cookies:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies != null){
    out.println("# Cookies: " + cookies.length + "<br/>");

    for (Cookie cookie : cookies){
        out.print("Name: " + cookie.getName( ) + " - ");
        out.print("Value: " + cookie.getValue( ) + "<br/>");
    }
}
else {
    out.println("No cookies found");
}
```

Results:

```
# Cookies: 2
Name: JSESSIONID - Value: DD299706C704FE80BC99C10EA2C6E9F9
Name: test - Value: test2
```

I can see in Chrome that both cookies are getting set with the correct names and values. Only the "test" cookie is getting displayed when I loop through the cookies; the "test[cuid]" cookie does not appear. I've found a few instances of others having issues with Tomcat throwing out cookies with special characters, but I haven't found a solution for it. As far as I can tell, RFC 2109 does not explicitly disallow brackets in version 1 cookie names.

Versions:

- Chrome 37.0.2062.124 m
- Apache Tomcat 8.0.9.0
- Java EE 8
- Spring Framework 4.0.1

Edit: I should note that the purpose here is to retrieve a cookie set by another web service, so any solution that involves changing the cookie name won't be viable.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know how to force Tomcat to accept my cookie, but I at least have a workaround for now. I call

```
String cookies = request.getHeader("Cookie");
```

and then parse it myself, i.e. tokenizing it by semi-colon ";" and then by equals "=".